# Best way to store data with pure ruby, no dependencies

Tags: ruby

I must create an application using only tools available in ruby core or stdlib. Do YAML or SQLite come with ruby? What are some of the other tools available that would allow me to store data to a file? What are their advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Have you checked [the core docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/) or [standard library docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/) to see what tools are available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby's stdlib is deep. Maybe too deep. I knew sqlite wasn't in there, but I figured something was. Here is what I found...

There are up to 4 different simple databases already in the stdlib:

- [PStore](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html) - Very simple persistent hash. Handles marshaling for you, so you can store trees of ruby objects. Pure ruby solution.
- [SDBM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/sdbm/rdoc/SDBM.html) - C-based key/value store. Ruby ships with the entire source so it should be portable across platforms. Simple string keys and values only.
- [GDBM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/gdbm/rdoc/GDBM.html) - Another string only key/value store. Uses GNU dbm. Its "enumerable" so its a little more hash-like. Possibly not very portable.
- [DBM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/dbm/rdoc/DBM.html) - Uses the DBM headers available on the platform ruby was compiled on, so it could be one of several DBM implementations (read: **not portable**). Yet another string only key/value store. That's 3. Unlike GDBM though this one will allow you to store non-string values and silently ruin them by calling `#to_s` or `#inspect`.

I might actually use [`PStore`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html) for small things myself now. SQLite is probably better, but PStore is undoubtedly simpler so if the job is small enough it makes sense.

You can also use serialization. [`Marshal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Marshal.html) will dump actual ruby objects and their data. [`YAML`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) can sort of do this as well. Using [`JSON`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)/[`YAML`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html)/[`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) you can finely control the format of the data. All of these can be used with [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/File.html) to write their output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can you ruby's stdlib `CSV` library to store any database data. Its format is very useful, for storing, exporting, and importing DB data. See documentation on CSV [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). As example, just do:

```
require 'csv'

# save
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
   csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
   csv << ["another", "row"]
   ...
end

#load
CSV.foreach("file.csv") do |row|
   row # => ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open 'local.rbdb', 'w+' do |f|
  f.write JSON.generate(write_target)
End
```

Build your `write_target` data in a typical manner, and then use JSON as a storage format.